# My app has had the pending publication status for over a day

Tags: google-play, google-apps, google-play-console

I uploaded my app bundle to the google play store over a day ago, and the status is still showing pending publication. I did some research and I read that it should only take a few hours to be rejected or accepted at most 24 hours. So I would just like to ask for advice should I upload another app bundle or just keep waiting?

Comment: Same here. 
I've been waiting for 5 days...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422790/why-is-my-application-update-still-pending-for-google-acceptance.

Comment: Contact the Play Console support. Only they will be able to find out what's going on.

Comment: I contacted google support 2 days ago, still no feedback. This is going to cost me my job.

Comment: Google accepted my update today, however only the one (1 out  of 5 apps) which I chatted about with some google person.

Comment: We waited for publication for 3 days. After then tried to upload application again. Now we are waiting for more than 24 hours.

Comment: My app was published today, seems to have taken 48 hours not 24 hours as most articles say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had an info from google. There is an ongoing issue, that they've resolved, but there is a back log. 
So we just need to wait.

Comment: Can I have a link to where you found this information? Please.

Comment: I was on chat available in the google play console app

Comment: Screen shot? haha